# why does --list.end() compile?

Tags: c++, list, stl, lvalue, rvalue

- list's `end()` returns a copy of the past-the-end iterator, right?
- Therefore, `list.end()` is an rvalue, right?
- the -- operator-function overloaded for list iterator takes a non-const reference, right?
- you can't bind rvalues to non-const references, right?

So how come does

```
std::list<int> lst;
// ... 
--l.end();`
```

compile?

As correctly pointed out, my third point is not necessarily right. But then how about this code which also compiles?

```
struct A{};

void f(A&)
{

}
A a()
{
    return A();
}

int main()
{
    f(a());
}
```

Comment: The third point is wrong.

Comment: I disagree that your second example compiles: http://ideone.com/V98wW3

Comment: @MarkRansom: That is MSVC++ extension, as confirmed by Armen himself.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> - the -- operator-function overloaded for list iterator takes a non-const reference, right?

This point is wrong. The `operator--` is a member function, and a member function can be invoked on a temporary. You don't pass any object to this member function as argument. so the question of binding rvalue to non-const reference doesn't arise in the first place.

---

As for the edit (passing *rvalue* to `f(A&){}`), it is a non-standard extension. I *guess* you're using Microsoft Compiler, because I know it has this non-standard extension which is stupid in my opinion.

Comment: Oh... right :) I'm silly. The resto of the logic is sound thouhg, isn't it? :)

Comment: Btw, does the standard mandate that -- be a member? Or is it implementation-defined?

Comment: Actually it is not necessarily a member function. The iterator could be a pointer.

Comment: @AndyProwl: It is a `std::list`, so it cannot be a pointer (I don't think so).

Comment: @AndyProwl: vector's iterator may be and **is** a pointer on most implementations (in release mode)

Comment: @Nawaz: But then the OP's example could make sense for `std::vector`, right?

Comment: @AndyProwl: If it were a vector and iterator were a pointer then -- wouldn't be a function, but an operator, and the standard mandates that --'s operand be an lvalue, so --v.end() would not compile

Comment: @ArmenTsirunyan: Exactly, so it would be implementation-dependent. So that means `--v.end()` is not portable. Interesting.

Comment: @ArmenTsirunyan, I was quite surprised to find you were right. I didn't expect to not be able to use `operator--` on a temporary, even if the operation had no observable side effects. http://ideone.com/als0zi

Comment: @ArmenTsirunyan: Updated my answer addressing the edit in your question. Let me know if you're really using MSVC++?

Comment: Btw by that MSVC++ extention, any rvalue can be passed as non-const reference or only temps?

Comment: In C++11 a member function can be invoked on an rvalue only if that member is declared with no ref-qualifier or with a ref-qualifier of "&&". It is theoretically possible for an implementation of std::list::iterator to declare a member `iterator& operator -- () &` so that the operator cannot be invoked on rvalues.

Comment: @Casey: That is not C++11. That is just *a proposal* for C++1y.

Comment: In my copy of the standard, 13.3.1 [over.match.funcs] p5 states: "For non-static member functions declared without a ref-qualifier, an additional rule applies: even if the implicit object parameter is not const-qualified, an rvalue can be bound to the parameter as long as in all other respects the argument can be converted to the type of the implicit object parameter." The clear implication is that binding an rvalue to the implicit this parameter of a non-static member function declared with a "&" ref-qualifier is not allowed.

Comment: @Casey: Which copy of the draft you've? n3485?

Comment: @Casey: Can you start a thread about what you're saying. I'm a bit confused. As far as I know member-function such as `void f() &&` is a proposal for next Standard only (and that is what is referred to as "ref-qualifier", I suppose?).

Comment: Yes, the trailing "&" or "&&" in a non-static member function declaration is a ref=qualifier, see 8 [dcl.decl] p4. Searching through the standard for occurrences of the phrase "ref-qualifier" will get you the gist of the feature. This was proposal N2439 for C++0x, and it did make the standard. To my knowledge no compiler implements it yet.

Comment: Correction: looks like Clang implements it according to http://clang.llvm.org/cxx_status.html since version 2.9.